# next.js debugging with vs code: unbound breakpoint - source maps expected in wrong folder?

Tags: visual-studio-code, next.js, vscode-debugger, react-devtools

I'm trying to set up the debugger for next.js on vs code. (I'm on windows, using the WSL and chrome).

The issue is that the breakpoints I try to set will be unbound. I guess this is due the source maps not connecting in some form?

I've set up the `.vscode/launch.json` as described in https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/debugging.

Here's the central error that shows up in the vs-code debugging console for the browser debugging session:

```
Could not read source map for file:///C:/shared/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/%40next/react-refresh-utils/dist/runtime.js {...}'
Could not read source map for file:///C:/shared/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/%40next/react-refresh-utils/dist/internal/helpers.js {...}'
```

So from this, I conclude that some part of the debugging toolchain expects my project/workspace root to be at `file:///C:/shared`. However the actual root is at `file:///C:/shared/work/workbench`.

---

My project

```
C:
  /shared/work/workbench
    /.vscode
      launch.json
      workbench.code-workspace
    {...rest}
```

Contents of `launch.json`

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Next.js: debug server-side",
      "type": "node-terminal",
      "request": "launch",
      "command": "npm run dev"
    },
    {
      "name": "Next.js: debug client-side",
      "type": "chrome",
      "request": "launch",
      "url": "http://localhost:3000"
    },
    {
      "name": "Next.js: debug full stack",
      "type": "node-terminal",
      "request": "launch",
      "command": "npm run dev",
      "serverReadyAction": {
        "pattern": "started server on .+, url: (https?://.+)",
        "uriFormat": "%s",
        "action": "debugWithChrome"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Contents of the workspace file:

```
{
  "folders": [
    {
      "path": ".."
    }
  ]
}
```